# made a function but it's not working

Tags: javascript, function

I have no idea why this is not working....

```
var changeIdValue = function(id, value) {
document.getElementById(id).style.height = value;
};

document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 40){
    document.getElementById("balklongwaarde").addEventListener("onkeydown", function(){ 
        changeIdValue("balklongwaarde", "60px")});
}

}
```

Can anybody help me why this is not working......
When I delete the code of the on keydown then the animation works without problems.
But I want that code executed after press on key down......

Comment: `onkeydown` is not an event, but `keydown` is.

Comment: Also, adding an event handler from *inside* another event handler is *probably* going to cause you all sorts of problems.

Comment: the identifier *changeIdValue* is rather misleading